# Can I visit in November to the UK?

Tags: uk, leave-to-enter

On June 21st, after I enlisted in the UK, the immigration officer took my passport and gave me a visa stamp. I received a second visa stamp on October 15th. I would like to know what the second stamp means? because the customs guard said I can't enter in December
[image]

Comment: How long have you stayed during each of the visits? And those aren't visa stamps

Comment: As the upper stamp says: [leave to enter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_to_enter) (leave as in *permission*) for the given duration and conditions. The lower stamp is the **entry** stamp with the date, place and resposible immigration officer number. A **leave to enter** expires when you leave the *Common Travel Area* and must be granted again on reentry.

Comment: @DJClayworth The passport page contains no Cyrillic translation for visa, so unlikely Bulgarian.

Comment: I've been coming to England for 5 years with the first stamp I entered for 3 weeks and with the second stamp the border guard told me I can't enter until December

Comment: In the UK an immigration officer if you can enter or not based on the circumstances that they probably see in their computer system. Nobody here can tell what these circumstances were or whether the statement was correct.

Answer (score 4):

Both the stamps say "leave to enter", meaning that you are allowed to enter the UK. They say that you can remain in the UK for up to six months from the date of the stamp below, i.e. 21 June 2022 the first time and 15 Oct 2022 the second. They are not technically "visa stamps". EU nationals do not need a visa to enter the UK.

The stamps do not give you permission to leave and re-enter - once you have left you need to get permission to enter again. (Just like you had to get permission to enter in October, even though October is less than six months after you entered in June.) So if you left in November 2022 you might or might not be re-admitted in December 2022. Each time you try to enter the immigration officer decides if you are eligible to be admitted. One of the reasons you can be refused admission is if they think you are trying to live in the UK by making repeated visits as a 'tourist'. If an immigration officer told you in October that you would not be readmitted in December then you should take that as a warning not to attempt to re-enter for a while after you have left, at least until well after December. It's not absolutely certain that you will be refused, but a refusal will make it harder for you to be admitted in the future, so don't do it.

Comment: The passport appears to be Hungarian (not Bulgarian) but the rest applies in the same way. https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/HUN-AO-03001/image-174474.html

Comment: Yes Im Hungary than you

Comment: I came home on the 5th of November, now I have no chance to travel back to November?

Comment: @DavidHajnalka no, just that the stamps have no bearing on that. Each time you arrive at the border, the border force officer will assess you for entry (unless you use the ePassport gates, which as an EU citizen, you're also entitled to do).

Comment: the gate won't open, there is an exit ticket, I didn't have enough proof to get a residence permit
( satulment) think that's why the gate doesn't open